# How to plot a line chart on factor datatype?

Tags: r, rcharts

I've a csv file with multiple columns. I'm considering only two of them, 'Time' and 'RiseOrFall'. Both are of Factor datatype. Sample data looks like:

```
Time RiseOrFallRiseOrFall  
12   32
34   0  
56   0
78   25
90   29
123  0
567  50
```

I'm trying to create a line chart in R that falls everytime 'RiseOrFall' hits 0 and rises when it's not 0. ('Time' on x-axis and 'RiseOrFall' on Y-axis)

I tried:

```
countFile <- read.csv(file = "counts.csv", nrows = 1000)[, c ('TIME','RiseOrFall')]

ggplot(data=countFile, aes(x=RiseOrFall)) + geom_line()
```

How can this be achieved in R (possibly using ggplot2 or anything)??

My expected output chart is as follows (The records in the sample data are very few.. Actual data is immensely large, with bigger 'RiseOrFall' values (Y-axis):
[image]

Answer (score 1):

try this.

I have set x-axis(Time) and y-axis(RiseOrFall) ticks to 6 units and 200 units respectively.

```
ggplot(data=countFile, aes(x=Time,y = TRPM)) + geom_line(colour="brown") + scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0),breaks = round(seq(min(countFile$Time), max(countFile$Time), by = 6),1)) + scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0),breaks = round(seq(min(countFile$TRPM), max(countFile$TRPM), by = 200),1))+ xlab("Time") + ylab("RiseOrFall")+ theme(panel.background = element_blank(),axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There must be a package for this type of data...
You could try this:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(zoo) #na.locf

#dummy data
countFile <- read.table(text="Time RiseOrFall  
12   32
34   0  
56   0
78   25
90   29
123  0
567  50",header=TRUE)

#assign values for every x value
filler <- data.frame(Time=min(countFile$Time):max(countFile$Time))
df <- merge(filler, countFile,all.x=TRUE)
df$RiseOrFall <- na.locf(df$RiseOrFall)

#plot
ggplot(df,aes(x=Time,y=RiseOrFall)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: Looks good.. Will try it out on my data now.. Thank you so much :)

Comment: And also can you please throw some light on why we used na.locf() here?? Are NA values creating problems here??

Comment: From your example plot, there is data for almost every point on x axis, so I created filler dataframe to merge with data and fill NAs with last known data point. So that when it is zero it stays zero until next non zero point.